# javafx binding combobox itemsProperty

Tags: binding, combobox, javafx-2, items

I have customized a combobox in order to add and remove an item in a combobox. 
Now I would bind my customized combobox, but it is not working and I don't understand what happen.

Here my sample example :

```
public class CbbxEditSuppr extends ComboBox<BoxItem> {

private TextField editor = null;
private ObservableList<BoxItem> items = null;



/**
 * Constructeur.
 * 
 * @param addedItems ObservableList<String>
 * @param prefWidth double largeur préférée
 */
public CbbxEditSuppr(ObservableList<String> addedItems, final double prefWidth) {
    // initialisation des attributs
    editor = this.getEditor();
    items = this.getItems();
    this.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
    // initialisation du contenu de la cellule
    this.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<BoxItem>, ListCell<BoxItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<BoxItem> call(ListView<BoxItem> p) {
            final ListCell<BoxItem> cell = new ListCell<BoxItem>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(BoxItem t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);
                    if (t != null) {
                        setGraphic(t.getBtn());
                        setText(t.getItem());
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
    // déininition du converter
    this.setConverter(new StringConverter<BoxItem>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(BoxItem cbbx) {
            if (cbbx == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return cbbx.getItem();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public BoxItem fromString(String id) {
            if (id != null) {
                final BoxItem box = new BoxItem(id, items);
                return box;
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    });
    // permet de prendre en compte la touche ENTER, et ajouter des valeurs a la liste
    this.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(final KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null && event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                if (editor.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                    addItem(editor.getText());
                    editor.clear();
                }
            } else if  (event != null && event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
                showPopUpMenu();
            }
        }
    });
    // propriétés editable et selection du premier element
    this.setEditable(true);
    /* ajout des valeurs a la liste d'items */
    if (addedItems != null && addedItems.size() > 0) {
        for (String stg : addedItems) {
            if (stg != null) {
                final BoxItem hbox = new BoxItem(stg, items);
                items.add(hbox);
            }
        }
    }
    this.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}

private void showPopUpMenu(){
    if (!this.isShowing()) {
        this.show();
    }
}

/**
 * Ajoute un item à la liste
 * 
 * @param stg String nom de l'item
 */
public void addItem(String stg) {
    if (stg != null) {
        items.add(new BoxItem(stg, items));
    }
}


/**
 * Retourne la description du contenu de la liste
 */
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder stgBuilder = new StringBuilder("[ ");
    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
        final BoxItem lastItem = items.get(items.size() - 1);
        for (BoxItem item : items) {
            if (item != null) {
                stgBuilder.append(item.getItem());
                if (!item.equals(lastItem)) {
                    stgBuilder.append(", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stgBuilder.append(" ]");
    return stgBuilder.toString();

}
}
```

and

```
public class ComboboxSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
}


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 450, 250);

    CbbxEditSuppr cbboxLeft = new CbbxEditSuppr(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList()), 200);
    CbbxEditSuppr cbboxRight = new CbbxEditSuppr(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList()), 200);

    cbboxLeft.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(cbboxRight.itemsProperty());
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(4);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    grid.add(new Label("To: "), 0, 0);
    grid.add(cbboxLeft, 1, 0);
    grid.add(cbboxRight, 2, 0);

    Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().add(grid);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
}
```

When I add a value in the right combobox it is working but not in the left combobox.
Do you have any advice please ?

Comment: What is "working" and what is "not working"? What did you expect and how does it behave? Do you have any errors? If so, do you have a stack trace?

Comment: My exemple shows 2 combobox : comboboxLeft and comboboxright. This combobox are binded. I don't have stack trace, my problem come from the behavior of the combobox. When I write in the right combobox and press ENTER, the text is added as item in combobox. This items is added in both combobox. Now, when I do the same in the left combobox, the item is not added in the combobox. This is my problem. the binding works only in one direction :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you "shadow" the `items` field. There are basically two properties called `items` in your combo box subclass: one that you define and one you inherit. When you call `itemsProperty()` you are getting the property wrapping the inherited `items`, and you are binding to that. In your class implementation, you then refer to the shadow `items` field, which is not bound.

You should remove the `items` field entirely from your class, and just refer to the inherited one by calling `getItems()`.

For example, do

```
if (addedItems != null && addedItems.size() > 0) {
    for (String stg : addedItems) {
        if (stg != null) {
            final BoxItem hbox = new BoxItem(stg, items);
            getItems().add(hbox);
        }
    }
}
```